# Maximum of 2 INTEGERS?

Tags: eiffel

What's the syntax for the maximum of 2 INTEGERS?

Eiffel documentation is so bad, literally could not find the answer to this simple question anywhere!

Or does it not exist and I have to use if-statements?

Comment: Did you read the docs?

Comment: @Mast Could not find it in the docs

Answer (score 1):

In most cases in Eiffel, the source is all the documentation you need. By right-clicking on a class' name in EiffelStudio, you can see its ancestor tree. You can also use the flat view feature to see all the inherited features of a class within the same editor.

Typically, `INTEGER` is an alias for `INTEGER_32`. `INTEGER_32` inherits from `COMPARABLE` (through `INTEGER_32_REF`). `COMPARABLE` provides the `max` and `min` features. Their signature is

```
max (other: like Current): like Current
```

meaning all descendants of `COMPARABLE` take and return another value of the same type as themselves.

Therefore:

```
local
  a, b, maximum: INTEGER
do
  a := <some value>
  b := <some value>
  maximum := a.max(b) -- or b.max(a)
end
```

Eiffel has a unified type system, which means every type is defined as a class, even 'primitive' types that get special treatments in most other languages. `INTEGER`, `CHARACTER`, `BOOLEAN`, `ARRAY` and other such basic types thus come with a rich set of features you can consult in their own class files like you would with any other type. Since operators are defined as regular features too, this is also the way to figure out exactly what operators exist for any given class.